# Getting Declared Methods - Java

Tags: java, class, reflection

Suppose I have the following three classes

**A.java**

```
public class A {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new C();
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class B {
    public B() {
        Method[] m = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    }

    public void hello() {

    }
}
```

**C.java**

```
public class C extends B{
    public C() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and I run the main method in class A. Well, it should instantiate class C, which in turn should call class B's constructor, to print out the declared methods. The output is `[]`. This is a surprise to me, as I was expecting the output to be (assuming all classes are in package called `test`):

```
[public void test.B.hello()]
```

So, what's wrong? And how do I get it so that this is the actual output?

Comment: Heh, even though it's the superclass' constructor, it's being called in the context of C; `this` is an instance of C.

Comment: If you know the object is also an instance of B (since you are in B constructor), you can also use simply `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()`

Comment: change the constructor statement to `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getClass` returns the class of the instance. In this case, this is `C`. There is no declared method in class `C`. You can solve your problem by also using the 'getSuperClass' method of the returned `Class` object:

```
Class c = this.getClass();
while (c != null) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getDeclaredMethods()));
  c = c.getSuperClass();
}
```

Comment: I see, so how do I fix that so that it outputs as I expect?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is use of the word `this` That implies the present context, which if `C` is a concrete subclass of `B` is `C`. To get `B's` methods, you need to traverse until you get to B. That's probably application logic dependent. One way would be the following.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class B {
    public B() {
        Class<?> parent = getClass();
        while(parent.getSuperclass() != null) {
            if(parent.getSuperclass() != Object.class) {
                parent = parent.getSuperclass();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        Method[] m = parent.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    }

    public void hello() {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful, although C-otto got it before you so I gave him the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

//Actually one can get the number of methods in different classes under the //different packages....
//Go and check the results................

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


    public class TestPackage {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
        {
            int count=0;
            Class c=Class.forName("java.util.Scanner");
            Method[] m=c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for(Method m1:m)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println(m1.getName());
            }
            System.out.println("The no. of methods are:"+count);

        }

    }
```