# Get a list of methods from a class which can be called from java source code

Tags: java, reflection

I need a way to get a list of all methods of a java class which could be called from a java file. I know that I can use `Class.getMethods`, but that does not work in some situations like I need it:

```
public interface IField<T> {
    public void setValue(T value);
}

public class Field implements IField<String> {
    private String value;

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Calling `Field.class.getMethods()` contains to `setValue` methods, but only the one with the `String` parameter is allowed to be called from a java source file.

Just remove the one with the "less specific" parameter is also not a solution becasue there might be situations like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {
    private Object value;

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Field extends AbstractBean {
    private Integer value;

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    };
}
```

where both `setValue` methods are ok to be called.

Comment: you may aswell want to loop through the superclasses of `Field`.

Comment: This can't work because of Type Erasure.

Comment: This should give you some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841952/getting-declared-methods-java

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found this [article on type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html). So I have to filter out the `bridge` methods via `Method.isBridge()`